# Retrieve user entered value of input box

Tags: javascript

I have an input box that lets the user type in data and I want the javascript to retrieve the same and save it in a variable. I tried but there seems to be some issues. Below is the link to fiddle. I want to do it with Javascript and not jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/un6oyhfo/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="demo" id="demo"/> 
<button onlclick="check()">Click me</button>

<div id="resp"></div>
```

JS:

```
function check(){
        var x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
        alert(x);
}
```

Thanks in advance to all who help.

Comment: oops! the fiddle link didnt come so here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/un6oyhfo/

Comment: The link didn't work because you're required to put the code in your question, not just a link.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle that is `onclick` not `onlclick` & you have to use `no wrap in <head>` in script settings for `check` function to be called.

```
<button onclick="check()">Click me</button>
```

[**FIXED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/un6oyhfo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you made spelling mistake.

```
 function check(){
            var x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
            alert(x);
    }


    <input type="text" name="demo" id="demo"/> 
    <button onclick="check()">Click me</button>

    <div id="resp"></div>
```

hope it helps.